# Как вывести на страницу содержимое json файла, который получается по ссылке?

Tags: php, json, dle

Есть вот такой JSON: [Топ 30 игроков на сервере](https://minecraft-statistic.net/api/server/top/vanillo/all/1)
Нужно вывести его и отформатировать через css. Сайт на движке DLE. Копался где ток смог, пытался что мог, ничего толкового не вышло. Уже совсем отчаялся, и больше некуда написать. Пытался на PHP через `file_get_contents`, но не выводилось совсем ничего

```
<?php

$j = @file_get_contents('https://minecraft-statistic.net/api/server/top/vanillo/all/1');
$data = json_decode($j);
echo ($data);
?>
```

[image: Пустое содердижимое блока, в котором должен быть JSON]

В общем, что делать дальше я не знаю. Буду очень признателен, если знатоки подскажут что и куда вписать. Дополнительную информацию, если потребуется, с удовольствием предоставлю.

Comment: json_decode превращает json в объект/массив, если с флагом. Не совсем понимаю ожидания от вывода объекта.

Comment: Так сказать, переведу слова @Ajantiss на более понятные символы :) `echo ($data);` => `var_dump($data);`

Comment: @InDevX 
Заменив `echo ($data);` на `var_dump($data);` на странице выводит NULL.

Comment: Есть telegram? Вопрос очень простой, даже не знаю есть ли смысл писать какой-то ответ. Просто помогу.

Comment: @Ajantiss телеграм есть, https://t.me/wackyipc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На сайте стоит блок от скриптов.
Надо сделать вид, что Вы - это браузер, а не скрипт. ))) 
Вот рабочий пример.

```
$context = stream_context_create(
    array(
        "http" => array(
            "header" => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.102 Safari/537.36"
        )
    )
);

echo file_get_contents("https://minecraft-statistic.net/api/server/top/vanillo/all/1", false, $context);
```

Comment: И правда заработало, спасибо Вам огромное.